# Unzip file in order to get csv files with read and write permissions

Tags: permissions

I am getting a few csv files from a .zip file I downloaded from a data website using and api token. 
I downloaded the file, and then unziped it to current directory, using the "unzip file.zip" instruction, which returned the .csv files it contained, but all these files had the "no read, no write" access value, when I checked the properties of each file. 
I can actually modify this access value by clicking and modifying properties on each file, but I don't want to do that. I would like to unzip the .zip file, setting the extracted files permissions to #Read and write" value at the same time I unzip the file. Is that possible?
Thanks!!!
I doubt the data website (Kaggle) wanted this permission problem to happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the same command window and directory where you did the `unzip file.zip` use `sudo chown --reference=. *` (`sudo` needed to change ownerships - security). Here's a demonstration:

```
                       # first, create an ownsership nightmare
walt@bat:~/tmp/test1(0)$ touch t y u
walt@bat:~/tmp/test1(0)$ sudo chown nobody t
walt@bat:~/tmp/test1(0)$ sudo chown root:root u
walt@bat:~/tmp/test1(0)$ sudo chown lp:lp y
walt@bat:~/tmp/test1(0)$ ll
total 24
-rw-rw-r-- 1 nobody walt 0 Nov 24 15:43 t
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root   root 0 Nov 24 15:43 u
-rw-rw-r-- 1 lp     lp   0 Nov 24 15:43 y

                        # now fix it with 1 command
walt@bat:~/tmp/test1(0)$ sudo chown --reference=. *
                        # see, fixed!
walt@bat:~/tmp/test1(0)$ ll
total 24
-rw-rw-r-- 1 walt walt 0 Nov 24 15:43 t
-rw-rw-r-- 1 walt walt 0 Nov 24 15:43 u
-rw-rw-r-- 1 walt walt 0 Nov 24 15:43 y
walt@bat:~/tmp/test1(0)$
```